# CoreOS - Failed to start windows mount share service

Tags: mount, coreos

I have setup a `mount.service` in coreOS, but when I reboot the server, I get:

```
$ sudo -i
Failed Units: 1
  mount.service
araweelo ~ # systemctl status mount
● mount.service - Mount share service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mount.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-06-22 10:45:58 BST; 50s ago
 Main PID: 695 (code=exited, status=32)

Jun 22 10:45:58 araweelo systemd[1]: Starting Mount share service...
Jun 22 10:45:58 araweelo mount.cifs[695]: mount error(101): Network is unreachable
Jun 22 10:45:58 araweelo mount.cifs[695]: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
Jun 22 10:45:58 araweelo systemd[1]: mount.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Jun 22 10:45:58 araweelo systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount share service.
Jun 22 10:45:58 araweelo systemd[1]: mount.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 22 10:45:58 araweelo systemd[1]: mount.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

here is my mount.service file

```
araweelo ~ # vim /etc/systemd/system/mount.service
[Unit]
Description=Mount share service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/opt/bin/mount.cifs //192.168.10.4/Apps/pegasus/operaII/Data/C /ccc/smb -o domain=server-apps.opera.local,credentials=/home/opera/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,ro

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
RequiredBy=docker.service
```

then:

```
araweelo ~ # systemctl enable mount
araweelo ~ # systemctl start mount
araweelo ~ # df -h
Filesystem                                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                    3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                       3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                       3.5G  460K  3.5G   1% /run
tmpfs                                       3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda9                                   114G   44G   65G  41% /
/dev/sda3                                   985M  589M  345M  64% /usr
tmpfs                                       3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /media
/dev/sda1                                   128M   66M   62M  52% /boot
tmpfs                                       3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /tmp
/dev/sda6                                   108M   52K   99M   1% /usr/share/oem
//192.168.10.4/Apps/pegasus/operaII/Data/C  558G  246G  313G  44% /ccc/smb
```

if I then reboot the server, I get the `Failed to start Mount share service`

Any advise on what I have missed is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a bit of a stab in the dark here, but should these two match?

```
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target
```

I know for an `After=` to take affect you also need a `Requires=` that matches the same service. Maybe that's the case for this as well?